# How can I make my script choose the right python interperter?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python

I have both 2.7 and 3.0 versions of the Python interpreter installed (on my Ubuntu 32 system), but one particular script uses 3.0.

Using

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -B
```

will not work when the program is run with `python myprogram.py`.

And I also need a solution that works also in Windows where I also have both python versions installed.

How can I make the script to run only with the right python version?

Comment: you can't, since `python` defaults to python-2.x in this case, so your script is already run with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which makes isolated Python environments easy.

Comment: And starting with Python3.3 [virtualenv made it into the standard library](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/venv.html) as `venv`

Answer (score 1):

```
python = Python to use. # This has to be the absolute path to Python executable

os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

This way you can restart the script with the python you want to use. Not really stylish.

Comment: If you use the exec(p) variants, you can run commands from your path

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you can't just launch the program with `python3 foo.py`, but it's possible to have a python2 program relaunch itself as python3 with something like this.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major != 3:
    import os
    # replace this process with a python3 process
    os.execlp("python3", "python3", *sys.argv)
```

It's a bad solution though, because now your python3 program can't use anything that's not valid python2 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [The wrong python interpreter is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904170/the-wrong-python-interpreter-is-called)

You have to choose a correct interpreter based on where you installed the desired version of Python and your system variables.

Comment: The answer there doesn't provide a portable solution that work also under Windows.